# Expect function not to be active when screen width is under 480

Tags: javascript, php

header.js

```
<script>



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {


                          let windowWidth = window.Width;
                          let withinMobile = 480;

                          let close = document.getElementById('close');
                          let mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
                          let header_links = document.getElementsByClassName('header-link');
                          let humberger = document.getElementById('humberger');
                          header_links = Array.from(header_links);

                          close.addEventListener('click', () => {

                          mySidenav.style.width = '0';

                             }, false);

                          humberger.addEventListener('click', () => {

                                            mySidenav.style.width = '250px';

                                               }, false);

                     while(windowWidth < withinMobile) {

                           for (let i = 0; i < header_links.length; i++) {

                           header_links[i].addEventListener('click', () => {



                                     mySidenav.style.width = '0';



                                                            }, false);

                          }

                          }







                          }, false);

</script>
```

home.php

```
<header>
        <div id='title'>
          <h1>花見川IT寺小屋</h1>
        </div>
 <?php include('js/header.php')?>
 <div id='mySidenav' class='sidenav'>
          <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='closebtn' id='close'>&times;</a>
          <a class='header-link' href='#trial' id='free-header'>無料体験</a>
          <a class='header-link' href='#curriculum'>学習内容</a>
          <a class='header-link' href='#price'>料金</a>
          <a class='header-link' href='#mentor' >講師</>
          <a class='header-link' href='#contact'>お問い合わせ</a>
        </div>

 <div id="humberger">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </header>
```

I want the function in the while context to be active while only "window.innerHight <  withinMobil" is true but it hasn't worked.

Mode detail, div tag which has id = 'mySidenav' cannot be closed (`width: 0;`) after open (`width: 250px;`).

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Don't check the width *before* attaching the event handler, do it inside said handler. Attaching the handler should happen always and only once, so there is no need for the `while` loop. Then, when the handler's code is actually executed is when you must check the widths, that's the IF.

```
document.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  () => {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let withinMobile = 480;

    let close = document.getElementById("close");
    let mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    let header_links = document.getElementsByClassName("header-link");
    let humberger = document.getElementById("humberger");
    header_links = Array.from(header_links);

    close.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => {
        mySidenav.style.width = "0";
      },
      false
    );

    humberger.addEventListener(
      "click",
      () => {
        mySidenav.style.width = "250px";
      },
      false
    );

    //while(windowWidth < withinMobile) <---- NOT HERE
    for (let i = 0; i < header_links.length; i++) {
      header_links[i].addEventListener(
        "click",
        () => {
          if (windowWidth < withinMobile) { //<---- HERE
            mySidenav.style.width = "0";
          }
        },
        false
      );
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: I appreciate for your solution for that. I wil try to do it.

Comment: @AY great to hear. If this answer was the solution, please mark it so, if not I encourage you to post an answer and mark it accepted. Think always of the future readers